# I want a button to be displayed as an image and open up the timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I want to include a button with my timepicker so that if the user clicks on the button, the timepicker is displayed. This works but I want the button to be displayed as an image rather than a button but I do not know how to do this. Below is my code at moment:

```
$('#durationpicker').trenttimepicker({
                timeFormat:'hh mm ss',
                hourGrid: 4,
                minuteGrid: 10,
                secondGrid: 10,
                showOn: 'button',
                button: '.timepicker_button_trigger'});
});
```

The image I want to be displayed is : `Images/clock.gif` and I include it in html code but it displsys both button and image with the button displaying the timepicker and the image doing nothing.

```
<p>
    <strong>3: Duration:</strong> 
    <input type="text" id="durationpicker" name="durationChosen" readonly="readonly" />

    <span class="timepicker_button_trigger">
        <img src="Images/clock.gif" alt="Choose Duration" />
    </span>
</p>
```

Does anyone know how to display the button as an image and be able to use it to display the timepicker?

The timepicker is trent richardson's timepicker which can be viewed [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Thanks

Comment: What button?! You have a text input and an image in your code. What are you even talking about?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally undo my code so it showed previous html line, I editted the code

Comment: Now what. Is your button the `<span><img /></span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use CSS to style the button. Set the `background-image` css property of the button to be the image. Then resize the button, remove all the other styling from it via css, and you're good to go.

This will give you something to start with. http://snipplr.com/view/14261/